# Bootstrap table not recognizing rows generated using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

For reference :
I'm working with [Bootstrap-table](https://bootstrap-table-docs3.wenzhixin.net.cn/home/) using Bootstrap v3.3.6
I'm trying to populate my table using AJAX and jQuery, but the problem is that when i do so none of bootstrap extensions seems to work with those rows.

I'm working on a data table using some extensions as the following :

```
`<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-key-events="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-resizable="true" data-cookie="true" data-cookie-id-table="saveId" data-show-export="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>ISBN</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="books-data">
   <!-- table data rows to be inserted here -->
</tbody>
```

`

If i'm filling the table using **PHP** everything seems to be working fine, by 'everything' i mean displaying data as well as the automatically added attributes to table rows as adding a chekbox in the first `<td>` and `data-index` attribute for every column in every row.

However, filling the table using **AJAX** only fills the table with data and there is no interaction between the table and its rows, no bootstrap-table attributes or checkboxes are added as well as no extensions seems to be working with those rows (for example export, rows selection ...)

**For more detail :**

- When embedding **PHP** code into table columns:

source code :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['isbn']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Generated code by bootstrap-table:

```
<tr data-index="0">
    <td class="bs-checkbox ">
        <input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td style>
        <!-- data -->
    </td>
    <td style> <!-- the same thing... --> </td>
</tr>
```

- When generating rows dynamically using **AJAX** :

  ```
  <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><!-- data --></td>
      <td><!-- data --></td>
      <td><!-- data --></td>
  </tr>
  ```

  - jQuery function used :

  `$(function()
      {
      $.ajax({
          url:"fetch_books.php",
          method:"POST",
          dataType:"json",
          success:function(data)
          {
              for(let count=0; count<data.length; count++)
                 {
                  let html_data = '<tr><td></td>';
                  html_data   += '<td>'+data[count].id_livre+'</td>';
                  $('#books-data').append(html_data);
                  }
          }
      })
  });`

I want the result to be the same as when i embed php inside each column in my table, i don't even know why i'm having this issue, i need some help.

Comment: You presumably have some code that calls `bootstrap-table` when the page first loads, and that's what's adding the extra attributes to the table. You'll need to find some way to call that event handler (or a similar one) in your Ajax success function.

Comment: I'm not using javascript to call bootstrap-table, simply adding the `data-toggle="table"` will activate it

Comment: Well, something must be calling an initialization function...

Comment: instead of using jQuery's append, I would read the docs and use their native append: https://bootstrap-table-examples3.wenzhixin.net.cn/#methods/append.html

Comment: according to bootstrap-table documentation [here](https://bootstrap-table-docs3.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/) there are two ways to activate bootstrap table, the first one is as it's said "Activate bootstrap table without writing JavaScript. Set `data-toggle="table"` on a normal table." and the second one if using javascript and initiating the table using `$('#table').bootstrapTable({columns: [{...}]});` i'm working with the first method.

Comment: @imvain2 i'm doing some tests before inserting `data` content in each column, i want to take full control of what is inserted, i don't think i can do so using `bootstrapTable('append', data)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using their method for loading JSON instead of your own jQuery?

From: https://bootstrap-table-docs3.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/#usage-via-javascript

"We can also use remote URL data by setting url: 'data1.json'.

```js
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
  url: 'data1.json',
  columns: [{
    field: 'id',
    title: 'Item ID'
  }, {
    field: 'name',
    title: 'Item Name'
  }, {
    field: 'price',
    title: 'Item Price'
  }, ]
});
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```

If you don't want to use their supplied method then maybe try adding the classes and data-index etc. that you see in the bootstrapped table to the table you're generating...

```
let html_data = '<tr><td></td>';
```

=>

```
let html_data = '<tr data-index="0"><td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>';
```

though I don't think that will get you working... it should at least style things correctly. You'll need to use a way that gets everything pulled into the DOM correctly. I'd try using Bootstrap-table's method for loading JSON they have supplied above. You might have to create a PHP script that takes some arguments and returns properly formatted JSON for their method to work.

Comment: I tried adding the attributes manually but as you said it didn't work, i looked into their method for loading JSON but as i said in my the comment i want to take full control of what is inserted and not just simply put json data, for example  wrapping some columns content inside a `<div>` tag, or doing some tests on a some data and dependingon their value displaying other information, i don't know how i can do so using this method.